# SQL results from a second table's ranges

Tags: sql, nested, between

I have a "date" table similar to:

```
id       date
----------------
1     2012-02-02
2     2013-02-02
3     2014-04-06
```

and a "date_range" table similar to:

```
   start           end
--------------------------
2011-01-01      2013-01-01
2014-01-01      2016-01-01
```

How can I get results from the "date" table where date does not fall between one of the "date_range" table entries?

The expected result is id->2, date->2013-02-02.

I've tried:

```
SELECT * FROM date
JOIN date_range
    ON date.date NOT BETWEEN date_range.start AND date_range.end
```

and the obvious fail:

```
SELECT * FROM date 
WHERE date.date NOT BETWEEN (SELECT start, end FROM date_range)
```

Comment: As noted in comments elsewhere, you should avoid the use of `BETWEEN`, especially when dealing with dates (you don't mention RDBMS, some are 'safer' than others).  [This blog post](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) (by @AaronBertrand) mentions some SQL Server-specific problems, but it actually applies to all ranges.  Generally speaking, ranges should be specified lower-bound inclusive (`>=`), upper-bound exclusive ('<'), even for 'simple' situations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT * FROM [Date] D
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 FROM Date_Range DR
    WHERE D.[Date] >= DR.[Start]
      AND D.[Date] <= DR.[End]
)
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/14c0b/3/0)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM date
LEFT JOIN date_range
    ON date.date >= date_range.start AND date.date <= date_range.end
WHERE date_range.start IS NULL
```

Comment: Don't use BETWEEN. It is much safe to use >= START and <= END. ALSO NOT BETWEEN will not give the correct result in this case.

Comment: @Declan_K Why not use BETWEEN? The only issue I've heard about is confusion over whether it's inclusive or exclusive. Is that it?

Comment: I have heard lots of argument abiut it. My intentiin wad to just show how close was the initial query.

Comment: I'm suprised why so many people suggest `LEFT OUTER JOIN` when they actually don't need a column from the second table. `EXISTS` or `NOT EXISTS` are more redable and more efficient in this case. Here's   also a pitfall if `date_range.start` is nullable. http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join

Comment: Well in some cases you need uniformity. Again,  my intention was to show how close was OP

Comment: And if i may add, there are cases that the OP describes part of his need or part of the table. So since he doesn't explicitly mentiin that he doesn't need a cilumn from that table, who knows?

Comment: @jyparask: Don't pick the wrong tool until you know that it's the right tool. OP is pretty clear in his requirement and also showed sql.

Comment: I used JOIN in one of my snippets that might lead someone into thinking I need the second table's columns. I only need results from the first table. Is using NOT EXISTS, in this case, more correct?

Comment: @rozz: Have a look at the link at the end of my last comment. That explains it much better than i could :)

Comment: @Declan_K - Note that the use of `<= END` is _identical_ (in most implementations) to `BETWEEN`, and is thus just as dangerous.  Depending on the RDBMS being used (and the exact 'type' of a date), it's not safe either (see my comment to the OP's question).

Comment: I disagree that it is "just as dangerous" - IHMO it forces you to make an explict decission to either use < or <= (both of which can be valid depending on the circumstances), which is no where near as bad as the implicit decision made for you by BETWEEN.

Answer (score 0):

This will do it. You need a LEFT OUTER JOIN so that all records from the DATETABE are included.

```
SELECT  D.ID
        ,D.DATE
FROM    DATETABLE D
LEFT OUTER JOIN
        DATE_RANGE DR
ON      D.DATE >= DR.START
AND     D.DATE <= DR.END
WHERE   DR.START IS NULL
```